# A markup link points or leads to something/somewhere?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Based on the wikipedia's definition for the [hyperlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink)

> A hyperlink **points** to a whole document or to a specific element within a document.

and some lines later:

> Internal wikilinks or intrawiki links **lead** to pages within the same wiki website.

if are both correct does that mean that the choice for the correct verb depends on the context of the sentence?

At the first sentence the link points to something (without taking any action) and at the second sentence the link leads (on click) from one place to another?

Comment: You're right. A hyperlink contains a link (Uniform Resource Locator) to a document, and can be said to *point* to it. Clicking on the link *leads* to the document. The wiki usage is, perhaps, forgiveable.

Comment: The second example should also technically use "point". Presumably the author was trying to avoid using the same word twice.

Comment: @D. Nelson: I see no justification for claiming that "technically" the verb should be ***point*** rather than ***lead***. And if it weren't for the fact that OP's cited context already uses ***link*** as a noun, that could just as well have been drafted into service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually in technical descriptions, links

> point to *somewhere*
>   The link *points* to the user's Instagram page.

The result of clicking on a link can

> lead you *somewhere*
>   The link will *lead* you to the related reference.
>
> bring you *somewhere*
>   Clicking on the link will *bring* you to the Facebook landing page.
>
> bring up *something*
>   The link will *bring up* the table of contents.
>
> download *something*
>   Click the link to *download* the OS image.

A link itself references or *points* at *something*.
Usually, it does not do anything on its own.
By clicking on the link other actions will occur.

If a link is a URL and automatically forwards the user, it is often called

> a redirect
>   [HTTP 302 Found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)

Comment: Oddly enough, a closed (or even locked) door can lead to somewhere (a garden, perhaps?) However, I agree with the distinctions that you have made.